# Timestamp in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, timestamp

I am determining the current time in swift with this code

```
let currentDate = Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000
```

the result looks like

```
1493199752604.24
```

The obtained value is in milliseconds right? What is the `.` inside the value?

I need to determine if the difference between two such date is equal or greater than 2 hours.

```
if (currentDate - oldDate >= 7200000){
// do something
}
```

is this code correct?

Comment: var Timestamp: String {
    return "\(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)"
} 

call this like Timestamp

Comment: That mysterious *"`.` inside the value"* shows that `timeIntervalSince1970` returns a *floating point* number (as you could see from the documentation, or by command-clicking on the property name in Xcode).

Comment: TimeInterval is in seconds so after `.` you've got fraction part of a second

Answer (score 1):

Try to use more benefits from `Swift`. Try to fetch difference in hours with usage of `dateComponents`.

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.current

let hours = calendar.dateComponents([.hour], from: Date(), to: Date())
```

Comment: let calendar = NSCalendar.current

let hours = calendar.dateComponents([.hour], from: Date(), to: oldDate)  This will calculate the difference between the current date and oldDate in hours? For example when the difference is two days the result will be 48?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is working fine. Checkout this example 
for difference greater than 2 hours

```
let currentDate = Date().timeIntervalSince1970*1000
let calendar = NSCalendar.current
let yesteraysDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: Date())
let oldDate = yesteraysDate!.timeIntervalSince1970*1000
if (currentDate - oldDate >= 7200000){
    print("greater or equal than two hour")  //"greater or equal than two hour"
} else {
    print("smaller than two hour")
}
```

if difference is less than 2 hours

```
let currentDate = Date().timeIntervalSince1970*1000
let calendar = NSCalendar.current
let yesteraysDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .hour, value: -1, to: Date())
let oldDate = yesteraysDate!.timeIntervalSince1970*1000
if (currentDate - oldDate >= 7200000){
    print("greater or equal than two hour")  
} else {
    print("smaller than two hour")  //"smaller than two hour""
}
```